# I'm trying to build a web scraper and can only pull one css element right now where there are 81

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to pull all 81 elements, but can only do one at a time this way. The page is dynamic so I'll have more than 81 elements going forward. The page also has several `sortableTable-number`attributes so I'm trying to avoid using it as beautifulsoup seems to get confused.

```
rreads1 = soup.select('tr.sortableTable-row:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(3) > span:nth-child(2)')
rreads = rreads1[0].get_text()
reads.append(rreads)
```

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks (urls and some code would be cool)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, improve your question and add a [MRP](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Based on the provided information you could loop the macthes:

```
reads = []

for item in soup.select('tr.sortableTable-row:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(3) > span:nth-child(2)'):
    rreads = item.get_text()
    reads.append(rreads)
```